# mongoDB cursor timeout in C++

Tags: c++, mongodb

I get the following error using mongoDB through its C++ API on a 64-bit installation:

> getMore: cursor didn't exist on server, possible restart or timeout?

The code snippet where the error is located is the following:

```
std::auto_ptr<mongo::DBClientCursor> cursor =
    connection.query("database.collection", mongo::BSONObj());

while (cursor->more()) {
     // Do stuff
     // Update contents of fields
     connection.update(...);
}
```

What the code simply does is updating the contents of each document's fields based on a specific data structure.

The code has been tested with a small data set, and it works perfectly fine, so I assume this is not a coding error, but rather a database-side error that is related to the size of the final data set.

My error looks similar to [this bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4680). The solution that is proposed there is to set the cursor to have no timeout, but there is no such function for the [C++ API](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_cursor.html), although it seems to exist for other languages.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: actually the solution seems to suggest setting batchSize not time out?

Comment: From the description in the bug report: "Iterating through a large record set stops before all documents were fetched, even when a small batchSize is used and the returned documents are tiny.
Using the no-timeout query option solves the problem but may not be an option for all users." Which, as I understand it, means that it is not a batch size-related problem.

Comment: but that bug was fixed to where using batchsize now would not cause the problem.